# Dbunit and hsqldb - identity generation

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb, dbunit

I'm working on a framework upgrade for one of my projects, and amongst other things I'm upgrading `Hibernate` + `HSQLDB` + `DbUnit`.

I have some testdata to form the basis of my dbunit test in an excel schema, and some data looking like this:

```
Table Something
id   | name
101  | Something
102  | Something else
```

With an entity looking like this:

```
@Entity
public class Something implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
```

In my previous version, when adding a new Something to the database, its `id` will continue the sequence of the testdata, making it `103`. But, in the new version it generates id `1`.

One of my testdata tables have id's 1-8, which results in a PK constraint violation, since the added entity will get id `1`.

Is there some setting I can use to get the old behaviour back, where the ids of the testdata act as a basis for the identity generation?

Comment: Mind showing some mappings?

Comment: Example mapping shown.

Comment: What about setting the "initial value parameter" of the @SequenceGenerator ?

Comment: Might work yes, how do I do that? I don't have a @SequenceGenerator-annotated class though.. One problem is that the different tables in test data use different sequences, but setting it to start at 10000 should be passed most of them..